# Triangle Inequality in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $p \in (0, \infty) \bigcup$ {$\infty$}

$||x||_p$ = ( $\sum_{k=1}^n |x|^p$)$^\frac 1p$ $p \in (0,\infty)$

$||x||_\infty$ = sup$|x_k|$ for $ 1 \leq k \leq n$

For which $p$ does the Triangle Inequality hold true?

Definition of Triangle Inequality for this problem is given as

$||x + y ||_p \leq ||x||_p + ||y||_p$

Can anyone help me with starting this? This is a problem on an exam review and the professor told us that there will be problems similar to this and I'm getting lost in all the notation.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Start with $n=2$, the general case is not much more difficult.

Comment: Ever heard of Minkowski inequality?

Comment: Thank you Giuseppe, I will begin there. And no, I have not heard of the Minkowski Inequality 251257 but I will look it up now! Thank you.

Comment: You find a proof here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Answer (score 1):

2) Note $||x + y||_{\infty} = \sup(x_k + y_k) ??\le?? \sup(x_k) + \sup(y_k)$

$\sup (x_k + y+k) = x_l + y_l$ for some $l \le n$ so $x_l \le \sup (x_k)$ and $y_l \le \sup (x_l)$ so $||x + y||_{\infty} = \sup(x_k + y_k) = x_l + y_l \le \sup(x_k) + \sup(y_k) = ||x||_{\infty} + ||y||_{\infty}$.